# Importing multiple .ui files to main.py file

Tags: python, database, user-interface, pyqt

I've managed to import my `main_GUI` file into my `main.py` file, but I'd like to implement another GUI, which would show as a result of clicking a button from the `main_GUI` file. Is that possible?

## this is my main file (bazapodataka.py) from which all the other .ui files would be called

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic 

class TestApp(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.ui = uic.loadUi("C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\BazaPodataka\database_GUI.ui")
        self.ui.show()  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TestApp()

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("BP Za bolnicu")
db.setUserName("postgres")
db.setPassword("zanoktica")
db.setPort(5432)
ok = db.open()

if ok:
    print("Connected to database")
else:
    print("Error connecting to database")

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## this is my main_GUI file (database_GUI.ui)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Main_GUI_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Main_GUI_Widget):
        Main_GUI_Widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Main_GUI_Widget"))
        Main_GUI_Widget.resize(300, 228)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_5"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.Add_button = QtGui.QPushButton(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.Add_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Add_button"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Add_button)
        self.Add_comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.Add_comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Add_comboBox"))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Add_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Add_comboBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
        self.Delete_button = QtGui.QPushButton(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.Delete_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Delete_button"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Delete_button)
        self.Delete_comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.Delete_comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Delete_comboBox"))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Delete_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Delete_comboBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"))
        self.Update_button = QtGui.QPushButton(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.Update_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Update_button"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.Update_button)
        self.Update_comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.Update_comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Update_comboBox"))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Update_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.Update_comboBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_4"))
        self.Search_button = QtGui.QPushButton(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.Search_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Search_button"))
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Search_button)
        self.Search_comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Main_GUI_Widget)
        self.Search_comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Search_comboBox"))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.Search_comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.Search_comboBox)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Main_GUI_Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Main_GUI_Widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, Main_GUI_Widget):
        Main_GUI_Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "Form", None))
        self.Add_button.setText(_translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "Add", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "asistira", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "kirurg", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "konzultant", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "nadgleda", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "operacija", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "pacijent", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "privatni_pacijent", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "sala", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "sestra", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "soba", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "zaduzena_za_salu", None))
        self.Add_comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "zaduzena_za_sobu", None))
        self.Delete_button.setText(_translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "Delete", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "asistira", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "kirurg", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "konzultant", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "nadgleda", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "operacija", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "pacijent", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "privatni_pacijent", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "sala", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "sestra", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "soba", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "zaduzena_za_salu", None))
        self.Delete_comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "zaduzena_za_sobu", None))
        self.Update_button.setText(_translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "Update", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "asistira", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "kirurg", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "konzultant", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "nadgleda", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "operacija", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "pacijent", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "privatni_pacijent", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "sala", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "sestra", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "soba", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "zaduzena_za_salu", None))
        self.Update_comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "zaduzena_za_sobu", None))
        self.Search_button.setText(_translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "Search", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "asistira", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "kirurg", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "konzultant", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "nadgleda", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "operacija", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "pacijent", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "privatni_pacijent", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "sala", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "sestra", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "soba", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "zaduzena_za_salu", None))
        self.Search_comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("Main_GUI_Widget", "zaduzena_za_sobu", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main_GUI_Widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Main_GUI_Widget()
    ui.setupUi(Main_GUI_Widget)
    Main_GUI_Widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## and my last gui file (kirurg_GUI.ui)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_kirurg_Widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, kirurg_Widget):
        kirurg_Widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("kirurg_Widget"))
        kirurg_Widget.resize(437, 301)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(kirurg_Widget)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_6"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.oib_kir_label = QtGui.QLabel(kirurg_Widget)
        self.oib_kir_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("oib_kir_label"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.oib_kir_label)
        self.oib_kir_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(kirurg_Widget)
        self.oib_kir_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("oib_kir_lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.oib_kir_lineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
        self.prezime_label = QtGui.QLabel(kirurg_Widget)
        self.prezime_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("prezime_label"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.prezime_label)
        self.prezime_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(kirurg_Widget)
        self.prezime_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("prezime_lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.prezime_lineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"))
        self.ime_label = QtGui.QLabel(kirurg_Widget)
        self.ime_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ime_label"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.ime_label)
        self.ime_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(kirurg_Widget)
        self.ime_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ime_lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.ime_lineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_4"))
        self.adresa_label = QtGui.QLabel(kirurg_Widget)
        self.adresa_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("adresa_label"))
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.adresa_label)
        self.adresa_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(kirurg_Widget)
        self.adresa_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("adresa_lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.adresa_lineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_5"))
        self.broj_telefona_label = QtGui.QLabel(kirurg_Widget)
        self.broj_telefona_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("broj_telefona_label"))
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.broj_telefona_label)
        self.broj_telefona_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(kirurg_Widget)
        self.broj_telefona_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("broj_telefona_lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.broj_telefona_lineEdit)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.kirurg_Add_button = QtGui.QPushButton(kirurg_Widget)
        self.kirurg_Add_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("kirurg_Add_button"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.kirurg_Add_button)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)

        self.retranslateUi(kirurg_Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(kirurg_Widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, kirurg_Widget):
        kirurg_Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("kirurg_Widget", "Form", None))
        self.oib_kir_label.setText(_translate("kirurg_Widget", "oib_kir (character(11) NOT NULL)", None))
        self.prezime_label.setText(_translate("kirurg_Widget", "prezime (text)", None))
        self.ime_label.setText(_translate("kirurg_Widget", "ime (text)", None))
        self.adresa_label.setText(_translate("kirurg_Widget", "adresa (text)", None))
        self.broj_telefona_label.setText(_translate("kirurg_Widget", "broj_telefona (varchar(12))", None))
        self.kirurg_Add_button.setText(_translate("kirurg_Widget", "Add", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    kirurg_Widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_kirurg_Widget()
    ui.setupUi(kirurg_Widget)
    kirurg_Widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So basically, I managed to implement my `database_GUI.ui` file into my `bazapodataka.py` file, but now I'd like to open my second GUI file (`kirurg_GUI.ui`), only if I select option `"kirurg"` from `comboBox` and click `Add`. Is that possible?

EDIT: Does my database_GUI.ui class forward all of it's buttons, comboboxes, etc. when imported in bazapodataka.py?

Also, is this the best approach for this? I mean, implementing outside GUIs to one main python file?

EDIT 2:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from database_GUI import Ui_Main_GUI_Widget
from kirurg_GUI import Ui_kirurg_Widget

class database_GUI(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Main_GUI_Widget):
       def __init__(self):
              QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
              self.setupUi(self)

              button = QtGui.QPushButton("Add_button")
              button.clicked.connect(self.open_kirurg_ui)

       def open_kirurg_ui(self):
              kirurg = KirurgUi()
              kirurg.show()

class kirurg_GUI(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_kirurg_Widget):
        def __init__(self):
              QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
              self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
       app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
       main_GUI = database_GUI()
       main_GUI.show()

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("BP Za bolnicu")
db.setUserName("postgres")
db.setPassword("zanoktica")
db.setPort(5432)
ok = db.open()

if ok:
    print("Connected to database")
else:
    print("Error connecting to database")

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For some reason, it won't connect to my db, unless that db code is put after this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
           app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
           main_GUI = database_GUI()
           main_GUI.show()
```

Comment: Hi! Why don't you use the same mechanism as for database_GUI.ui? You should only connect it to `Add_button.clicked` signal.

Comment: Ok, I used the same mechanism and now it opens both GUIs, but I don't now how to implement Add_button.clicked signal? Plus, combo box has to be set on "kirurg", and then after I click Add, it should open new GUI. I'd like to make it so that every other combo box option, opens new GUI.

Comment: Deusdies has already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible, but I'd consider some refactoring.

Let's say you have three files:

- `bazapodataka.py` - which is your main python file that will load all UIs
- `database_ui.py` - which is your first UI
- `kirurg_ui.py` - your UI that gets called when a button is clicked in the first UI

Your `bazapodataka.py` should look something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from database_ui import Ui_Main_Gui_Widget #importing UI as py files generated by pyuic
from kirurg_ui import Ui_kirurg_Widget

class TestApp(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Main_Gui_Widget): #inherit from Ui_Main_Gui_Widget
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi() #call the Ui_Main_Gui_Widget's setupUi method

        self.kirurg_Add_button.clicked.connect(self.open_kirurg_ui)

    def open_kirurg_ui(self):
        if self.Add_comboBox.currentText() == "kirurg":
            kirurg = KirurgUi()
            kirurg.exec_()


class KirurgUi(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_kirurg_Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi()


db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("BP Za bolnicu")
db.setUserName("postgres")
db.setPassword("zanoktica")
db.setPort(5432)
ok = db.open()
if ok:
    print("Connected to database")
else:
    print("Error connecting to database")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TestApp()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: I did not test the app, but it should work.

Pozdrav

Comment: I did what you wrote and it opens database_GUI (the main one), but nothing happens after clicking Add. Also I had to make some adjustments in order for code to work, I'll put it in my first post as edit so you can see. And one more thing, I'd like to make some sort of IF clause, only if comboBox is set to "kirurg" (it's second option) AND if I click Add, it opens kirurg_GUI

Comment: Yeah, I've had the same idea just a minute ago, and now it shows kirurg  screen for a blimp of a second and then it goes away. Also, what about adding if clause? :)

Comment: @Luka I've modified the code. Change the `show()` to `exec_()` and see if that sticks. Also, I've modified it for your if check with the `QComboBox`, assuming you meant the `self.Add_comboBox`

Comment: Using exec_() showed me an error, but I found out that putting global variable of name kirurg in that function solves that problem. And yes, the comboBox part works, many many thanks :)